# Curl command with special characters renames the file in the destination unix server

Tags: curl

I am trying to execute below command , which is trying to download one specific file from website and put the file in LINUX server through below CURL command.

```
curl -D ~/header.txt --ntlm --request GET --netrc "http://Testwebsite.net/files/1633070958_myfile_test_%E6%8C%87%E4%BA%8B%E5%AD%97%20zh%C7%90sh%C3%ACz%C3%AC.pdf" -o /attachment/3390773_mytest_test_指事字zhǐshìzì.pdf
```

The destination file in server is named differently .

actual result : `3390773_mytest_test_æŒ‡äº‹å­—zhÇshÃ¬zÃ¬.pdf`

expected result : `3390773_mytest_test__指事字zhǐshìzì.pdf`

please post your tips to fix this.

Comment: What is your current locale? What does `locale` output? Does it not work with `-O` on place of `-o` and its argument?

Comment: [Test_user_uat@attachments]$ ls 3390294_Chandana_test*
3390294_Chandana_test_æäºå­zhÇhÃ¬zÃ¬.pdf
[Test_user_uat@attachments]$ ls 3390294_Chandana_test* | hexdump -C
00000000  33 33 39 30 32 39 34 5f  43 68 61 6e 64 61 6e 61  |3390294_Chandana|
00000010  5f 74 65 73 74 5f e6 8c  87 e4 ba 8b e5 ad 97 7a  |_test_.........z|
00000020  68 c7 90 73 68 c3 ac 7a  c3 ac 2e 70 64 66 0a     |h..sh..z...pdf.|
0000002f

Comment: My locale output is UTF 8[Test_user_uat@test_attachments]$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

Comment: Thanks for your inputs , we understand the issue with tool tectia SSH , while in putty it works as expected,